# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'data'

Tags: file

I want to open a file named data and put in in a var called base_donnees

```
base_donnees = open("data")
```

This is the file  in question:

```
T,rho,mu
0,999.8,1.78e-3
5,1000,1.52e-3
10,999.7,1.31e-3
15,999.1,1.14e-3
20,998.2,1.00e-3
25,997.0,0.89e-3
30,995.7,0.80e-3
40,992.2,0.65e-3
```

But I get this error and I should have permission to access it since I took it from my class repository in github:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'data'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the read&write permission for this file.

For mac: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-permissions-for-files-folders-or-disks-mchlp1203/mac

For windows: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/give-permissions-to-files-and-folders-in-windows/78ee562c-a21f-4a32-8691-73aac1415373